# Make a table fill the entire window

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, stylesheet

How can I make a HTML table fill the entire browser window horizontally and vertically?

The page is simply a title and a score which should fill the entire window.  (I realise the fixed font sizes are a separate issue.)

```
<table style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <tr style="height: 25%; font-size: 180px;">
        <td>Region</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 75%; font-size: 540px;">
        <td>100.00%</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I use the above code, the table width is correct, but the height shrinks to fit the two rows of text.

I'm likely to be forced to use *Internet Explorer 8* or *9* to present this page.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use position like this to stretch an element across the parent container.

```
<table style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;">
    <tr style="height: 25%; font-size: 180px;">
        <td>Region</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 75%; font-size: 540px;">
        <td>100.00%</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for those answers!  I notice in IE8 that this seems to extend about another 10px too far.  Is there an easy fix for this, or should I stick with `height: 95%`?

Comment: probably margin:0 or padding:0 fixes that.

Comment: This doesen't prevent the table to extend vertically above the page.

Comment: Mind showing me some code so I can help? The table will fill the width and height of its parent. So if the parent container does it, so would the table.

Comment: The issue with this solution is that if you're trying to create a header you'll want the next element to go below this one, but absolute positions makes it intangible to the rest of the elements in the DOM.

Comment: Absolute positioning is relative to its parent container. That means '<div style="position:relative"> will contain/constrain an absolutely positioned element assuming no other rules are cascading into it.

Comment: you are rendering white space in the html.

Answer (score 12):

you can see the solution on http://jsfiddle.net/CBQCA/1/

OR

```
<table style="height:100%;width:100%; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;border:1px solid">
     <tr style="height: 25%;">
        <td>Region</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 75%;">
        <td>100.00%</td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

I removed the font size, to show that columns are expanded.
I added `border:1px solid` just to make sure table is expanded. you can remove it.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me:

```css
<style type="text/css">
#table {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

For me, just changing Height and Width to 100% doesn’t do it for me, and neither do setting left, right, top and bottom to 0, but using them both together will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Below line helped me to fix the issue of scroll bar for a table; the issue was awkward 2 scroll bars in a page. Below style when applied to table worked fine for me.
`<table Style="position: absolute;  height: 100%; width: 100%";/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<html style="height: 100%;">
    <body style="height: 100%;">
        <table style="height: 100%;">
        ...
```

in order to force all parents of the `table` element to expand over the available vertical space (which will eliminate the need to use `absolute` positioning).

Works in Firefox 28, IE 11 and Chromium 34 (and hence probably Google Chrome as well)

Source:
http://www.dailycoding.com/posts/howtoset100tableheightinhtml.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That is because, of course, there is no ACTUAL page height. Keep in mind that you scroll throughout the contents of a page vertically not horizontally, creating a limited width but unlimited height. What the selected answer did was to make the table take up the visible area and stay there no matter what(absolute positioning).So theoretically what you were trying to do was impossible